# How to WebDAV PROPFIND response and protocolling with OpenOffice

Tags: webdav

I got the following WebDAV request from Open Office Calc. You can see my server response under it. I suppose that this is not the correct answer beacause after my server send the ansver got the anoterh PROPFIND request with the same parameters. After that HEAD and GET messages follows. Can somebody correct it Please? And explain what the Calc actually request in this PROPFIND sequence?

I would like to transfer a simple html table from my C code for the Open Office Calc.

I am thankful
Peter

Request

```
PROPFIND / HTTP1.1
Host: WXPPx86BE-2318:80
user:-Agent: OpenOffice/4.0.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Depth: 0
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Lenght: 230

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:"/>
  <prop>
   <resourcetype xmlnx="DAV:"/>
   <IsReadOnly xmlnx="http://ucb.openoffice.org/dav/props/"/>
   <getcontenttype xmlnx="DAV:"/>
   <supportedlock xmlnx="DAV:"/>
  </prop>
</propfind>
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Lenght: XXXX

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:">
<D:response xmlns:lp1="DAV:" xmlns:lp2="http://192.168.0.49/"> 
<D:href>/</D:href> 
<D:propstat> <D:prop> <D:resourcetype>
<D:collection/></D:resourcetype>
<IsReadOnly xmlns="http://ucb.openoffice.org/dav/props/">false</IsReadOnly>
<D:getcontenttype>text/html</D:getcontenttype>
<D:supportedlock>
<D:lockentry>
<D:lockscope><D:exclusive/></D:lockscope>
<D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype>
</D:lockentry>
<D:lockentry>
<D:lockscope><D:shared/></D:lockscope>
<D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype>
</D:lockentry>
</D:supportedlock>
</D:prop>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
</D:propstat>
</D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Dav!

The XML above looks correct to me. But just a couple of general pointers from my own experience..

- PROPFIND is not enough by itself. Clients also use HEAD and OPTIONS requests to discover server capabilities.
- Typically a major Dav client will do about 10 http requests for a single user action such as opening or saving a file.
- ALL requests sent by the client must succeed, and must be semantically correct.

A common mistake among new developers working with Dav is just stubbing out responses, eg Lock IDs. But dont ever do that, each response must be semantically correct, or the logic inside the client will fail and it will abort the process.

Unfortunately, its often hard or impossible to get access to logs from the dav client, so it can be very hard to work out what's wrong. The only approach which works (imho) is to make sure that you implement everything, and everything is correct.

You might find it easiest to use a Dav server library such as SabreDav or Milton (my (non-free) project - http://milton.io)

Comment: I confirm that obtaining logs from the dav client is quite impossible. I could inspect the requests by 1. bootstrapping a webdav server using apache2 + mod_dav (on docker) and 2. using wireshark to inspect the traffic. Then, I could have good examples and requirements from LibreOffice and work on my own application. When things were equivalents, I confirm that opening and saving a file worked.